# php current password check and update hash password

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I creating PHP user hash password updating script this script is not working and not showing any error message All time display Your old password is incorrect message only I have tried to do that's but it's not working I want to create user old password check and updating new password

Here is my code

```
<?php
include "database/config.php";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $old_password = password_hash($_POST['old_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $new_password = password_hash($_POST['new_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $con_password = password_hash($_POST['con_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id= ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['user_id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt == $old_password) {
        if ($new_password == $con_password) {
            $stmt = $con->prepare = "UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
            echo "Update Sucessfully";
        } else {
            echo "Your new Password is not match ";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Your old password is incorrect";
    }
}
```

Here is my html form

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <input name="old_password" type="text" id="old_password" value="" placeholder="Current Password" required>
    <input name="new_password" type="text" id="new_password" value="" placeholder="New Password" required>
    <input name="con_password" type="text" id="con_password" value="" placeholder="confirm new password" required>
    <input type="submit" name="changePass" value="change password" class="submit2" />
</form>
```

Comment: What happens when you set error reporting to true?  Put this at the top of your script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);` `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: I have not used error reporting

Comment: Put those 3 lines at the top of your script -- It should provide you with all `NOTICES`, `WARNINGS` and `FATAL ERRORS`

Comment: displaying  Your old password is incorrect message only

Comment: You need to verify the old hashed password, not rehash it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard is correct ..  You need to be doing something like `password_verify($_POST['old_password'],$stmt)`

Comment: You never `fetch` anything from the initial query. You cannot just do this `if ($stmt == $old_password) {`

Comment: What error message?

Comment: I changed it's display like this error message Notice: Undefined variable: password_verify in C:\xampp\htdocs\zblog\change-password.php on line 622

Comment: It is because you never fetch anything from the select query to compare to. You cannot just compare to `$stmt`

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is hashing, and then comparing two hashes .. This is the incorrect way to go about it since the hashes will never exactly match (otherwise what good is encryption?)  --  You are doing:

```
$old_password = password_hash($_POST['old_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

When you should just be doing:

```
$old_password = $_POST['old_password'];
```

Then it's a simple chek:

```
if (password_verify($old_password, $stmt)) { {
    if ($new_password == $con_password) {
        $stmt = $con->prepare = "UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
        echo "Update Sucessfully";
    } else {
        echo "Your new Password is not match ";
    }
 } else {
    echo "Your old password is incorrect";
 }
```

---

**ALSO**

As Jay mentioned .. You need to be fetching something .. You are returning an object at this point with:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id= ?');
```

An Object does no good for this comparison.  You need a string.  If you are expecting 1 result you could add `fetch_array()[0]` to the end of that query.  `fetch_array` converts your `Object` into a single dimensional array.  The `[0]` simply is the array *index* you're wishing to assign to `$stmt` as such:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id= ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['user_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt = $stmt->fetch_array()[0];
```

Comment: You need to fetch something before you can verify.

Comment: Good edit, but you're going to have to be more explicit to help this OP.

Comment: Better explaination?

Comment: You need to fix the `if` statement and show the whole thing *in order*. I fear the OP doesn't understand what to do.

Comment: I added display error Warning: password_verify() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\zblog\change-password.php on line 622

Comment: Read the *ALSO* note .. You need to be making `$stmt` a string.

Comment: display one error Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array() in C:\xampp\htdocs\zblog\change-password.php on line 621

Comment: what does `print_r($stmt)` or `var_dump($stmt)` show?  You should be able to determine how to arrive at a string from that output.

Comment: Zak I changed it's display same results like this Warning: password_verify() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\zblog\change-password.php on line 625

Comment: You need to figure out how to extract a string from that object .. When you used `print_r` or `var_dump` that simply gives you the objects structure (as a troubleshooting tool) -- It's up to you to extract the string at that point ..